# Error in NonlinearModelFit for Complex differential Equation

Tags: differential-equations, fitting, finite-element-method, nonlinear

I am trying to create a model that will fit data to a complex differential equation generated from NDSolve. The format that I have begins with ParametricNDSolveValue to find a general function where the parameters can be plugged in, as such.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
ϵ = 10^-9;
reg = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 5, {x}];
eq = {-d1 Laplacian[u1[t, x], {x}] + 
    D[u1[t, x], t], -d2 Laplacian[u2[t, x], {x}] + D[u2[t, x], t]};
ic = {u1[0, x] == 5, u2[0, x] == 0};
bc1 = NeumannValue[-dm (Log[u1[t, x] + ϵ] - 
      Log[u2[t, x] + ϵ] + Δμ), x == 5];
bc2 = NeumannValue[-dm (Log[u2[t, x] + ϵ] - 
      Log[u1[t, x] + ϵ] - Δμ), x == 5];

c = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq[[1]] == bc1, eq[[2]] == bc2, ic}, {u1, 
   u2}, {t, 0, 100}, 
  x ∈ reg, {d1, d2, dm, Δμ}]
```

This NDSolve will give me two interpolating functions when computed, but I need them to be in one single function, so I use a piecewise that manipulates the data a little bit. I also use it to generate some artificial data for the actual fitting aspect of the model.

```
{U3, U4} = c[RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomInteger[{1, 3}], RandomReal[]];
U[t_, x_] := Piecewise[{{U3[t, x], 0 <= x < 5}, {U4[t, 10 - x], 5 < x <= 10}}];
data = Flatten[Table[{t, x, U[t, x]}, {t, 0, 100, 10}, {x, 0, 10, 1}], 1];
Plot3D[U[t, x], {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 100}, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotTheme -> "Marketing", PlotRange -> All]
```

Now the actual fitting part comes into play, and here is where the issues arise. I am not aware of if this is correct, but I am using an example model given to me by a peer to use for mine. I believe it defines a fitting form first, and then it attempts to do the actual fitting. The fitting form code is below. Because I want it to give me one function, I use the same piecewise code as above to generate one singular function, but I have to use the "Part" function since I cannot define a "{U5,U6}" set like before.

```
Clear[model];
model[d1P_?NumberQ, d2P_?NumberQ, dmP_?NumberQ, ΔμP_?NumberQ] := 
(model[d1P, d2P, dmP, ΔμP] = 
   Piecewise[{{Part[c[d1P, d2P, dmP, ΔμP], 1][t, x], 0 <= x < 5}, 
     {Part[c[d1P, d2P, dmP, ΔμP], 2][t, 10 - x], 5 < x <= 10}}])
```

After the fitting form (which may be the issue entirely), I have the actual fit using the NonLinearModelFit function. However, I get an error when I attempt to run it after all the proceeding code.

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, model[d1P, d2P, dmP, ΔμP][t, x], {d1P, d2P, dmP, ΔμP}, {t, x}]
```

[image: Error from the notebook]

What is going run and what should I look into? I have no knowledge of how this function works and if I even set it up (or if it can handle a piecewise of two interpolating functions), so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This issue is not with `NonlinearModelFit` but rather with the output of `model`.  You simply don't get a number when evaluating `model[d1P, d2P, dmP, ΔμP][t, x]`.  That's what the error message is telling you.  Someone else will know how to fix that.